# How can I transition from carpeted stairs to an engineered hardwood floor?

Tags: hardwood-floor, carpet, transition

I want to replace the carpet in my bed rooms(actually the whole 2nd floor) with engineer hardwood floor. The stair is from 1st floor to 2nd floor which will keep carpet. But I can't imagine how/where I need to do the transition. I don't have any experience, appreciate if anyone can give me some suggestion.

Here is the picture of the current situation:

[image]

Comment: What's at the bottom of the stairs?  More carpet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One potential location is on the last rise on the stairs.  This is depicted below on my crude diagram.  Make the cut of the carpet right under the lip of the top of the 2nd floor.  Use a piece of trim to hide the cut and make it finished.

[image: Location 1]

Other options include:

- Create a small carpet landing at the top.
- Take the carpet off all the stairs and make the stairs hardwood as
  well.

Your second question:

Probably.  When you take the carpet up, see if there is a gap under the baseboard.  if so, see if the hardwood fits in the gap.  If so, you can leave it on.  If not, you should be able to carefully remove the baseboard, install the floor, and the re-attach the existing baseboard pieces when floor is finished.

Comment: Thanks a lot! BTW, since I am going to use engineer hardwood, is there any good way to handle the end of the last piece? see http://www.evernote.com/shard/s1/sh/bf6ea873-b5ff-4305-90f4-6a55bbe4b8b0/5f536935fc628ba5d691805c54b5ed00

Comment: That spot is referred to the stair tread nosing (or nose). That should help narrow a web search for ideas. Ideally the flooring manufacturer has a piece to do that. No matter what you do, be careful you don't create a lip or other tripping hazard right at the top of the stairs.

Comment: The keyword "stair tread nosing" really helped! thanks!